# Basic about function in OOP Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }
```

What does above code do? In my project file I search for setTo function and there's no setTo() found, so how does it been called? and the this refer to?

Comment: search the web for java setters/getters and also javaBeans

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have three questions. I'll answer them in order:
**What does above code do?**
These methods allow code from outside the class to set and retrieve the `to` variable value within the class, even if it's been declared private.
**In my project file I search for setTo function and there's no setTo() found, so how does it been called?**
Spring uses the setter methods to do dependency injection. Basically there's Java in Spring libraries that will automatically look for these variable names and call a corresponding method named after the variable, with 'set' in front of the name.
IDEs can generate both getters and setters automatically, and since you need the setters for Spring, people tend to also have the IDE generate the getters, even if they don't plan on using them.
**and the this refer to?**
`this` is a scoping keyword.
`this.to` refers to a variable named `to` that's part of the class where these getter/setter methods are. The '`to`' without the '`this.`' refers to the `(String to)` in the parameter definition, which is the one that a call would pass in.

Answer (score 0):

In Object Oriented programming it is wrong for other classes to have access to some variables in your program simply because as you write larger programs some of your variables can be changed without your knowledge. To stop this we make the variables in your class private and create getters and setters. The first method is a setter which can set a private variable in your class to what the user wants. This will stop many errors from occurring. The

```
  this
```

is a keyword which is calling the current class you are in. If the variable passed in as a parameter is the same as the private variable declared at the top of your class, we use *this* to refer to the variable at the top of the class.

Answer (score 0):

This two methods are the `setter-getter` for the property `to` of your class.

You source code may not call these method but still these methods are called by some framework/third party library such as `JSF`, `Spring` those you are using in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, "Getters" and "Setters" are methods specifically designed to interact with Fields without directly manipulating the field.  This is called " FieldEncapsulation"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_encapsulation

Instead of directly accessing a Field, you access it's methods.  You can restrict usage in your code, i.e., not allow any getting, or setting, or both.

If you have access to the Field itself, you can do anything, but if you split up methods for the field, then you are able to

1. better manipulate the field actions.
2. make your code cleaner (`text.setName(name)` is easier to understand than writing `text = "name";`
3. restrict access to parts of your code (depending who is using your code).

---

Some pieces of code also use the getters/setters specifically, and not the fields, so making sure your fields have Getters/Setters is a good practice overall.

For example, Apache BeanUtils.copyBean() will NOT copy a bean if getters/setters are not set.

---

You asked what

```
public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }
```

means so instead of saying

```
String setTo = "hello"; 

or 

String setTo2 = setTo;
```

you can do

```
setTo("hello");

or

String s2 = getTo();
```

So setTo requires a String parameter, and then will get our "to" field `String to;` to whatever is the value of the parameter.

getTo will then get our field to, and return it.

There are also instances where people will add additional code into the set/get statements, but I'm not sure how common that is.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

These are **Getter** and **Setter** methods for a Class global String variable (or property) named '**to**'. The related Class is usually the very same Class the *getter* and *setter* methods are contained in as is the variable they are related to. If you look at the top of the Class code just under the Class constructor you should be able to locate the String variable '**to**', for example:

```
private String to = ""; // or something similar
```

Usually, if there is a variable named '**to**' there is also another variable named '**from**' (but not always) and it to may also have *getter* and *setter* methods contained within the class.

**Getter** and **Setter** methods allow you to retrieve and modify variable data contained within a Class from another Class during run-time, for example:

```
MySpecialClass myClass = new MySpecialClass();

// Use the 'to' variable getter to retrieve its current 
// contents and place those contents into the 'toVar' variable.
String toVar = myClass.getTo();

// Display the contents...
System.out.println(toVar);  

// Set the 'to' variable within the MySpecialClass Class 
// to hold the string "I hold this now"...
myClass.setTo("I hold this now");

// Use the 'to' variable getter again to retrieve its new 
// contents and place those contents into the 'toVar' variable.
toVar = myClass.getTo();

// Display the contents again...
System.out.println(toVar);
```

Now code contained within the **MySpecialClass** can use the '**to**' variable with its new data value. You will notice that Java Class Libraries do things this way, very much the same as setting specific properties for a JButton or JLabel etc. etc.